# Can a swarm be intimidated?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, skills, swarm, social-stats

Last night the party ran into a swarm (this one was rats) which proved rather difficult, but interesting, for them to overcome. The bard, looking for an effective way to light them on fire cast [blistering invective](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/blistering/) which requires a successful intimidate check. This got us wondering two things:

1. Can a swarm be verbally intimidated, as the spell requires?
2. Can a swarm be demoralized by an intimidate check?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [SRD](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types#TOC-Swarm):

> A swarm is immune to any spell or effect that targets a specific number of creatures (including single-target spells such as disintegrate), with the exception of mind-affecting effects (charms, compulsions, morale effects, patterns, and phantasms) if the swarm has an Intelligence score and a hive mind.

[Demoralize Opponent](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/intimidate#TOC-Demoralize-Opponent) per se would not work, because it is an effect that targets one opponent and Rat Swarm does not posses Hive Mind feature.

**But!**

Blistering Invective affects 30-ft. radius, thus overriding above limitation, as specific beats general.

Sadly, it also changes general *"verbal threats and displays of prowess"* of Intimidate to very specific *"insulting tirade"* and spell has [language-dependent descriptor](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic/#TOC-Descriptor-). Rats normally do not have any languages listed, so this spell will not work on them, unless you can make them understand first:

> **Language-Dependent**: A language-dependent spell uses intelligible language as a medium for communication. If the target cannot understand or hear what the caster of a language-dependent spell says, the spell has no effect, even if the target fails its saving throw.

Answer (score 0):

### Blistering Invective could be effective against Rat Swarms, but it is unlikely. Other Swarms may be immune or not, depending on their composition.

While [Swarms have their own immunities](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types#TOC-Swarm-Subtype):

> A swarm is immune to any spell or effect that targets a specific number of creatures (including single-target spells such as disintegrate), with the exception of mind-affecting effects (charms, compulsions, morale effects, patterns, and phantasms) **if the swarm has an Intelligence score and a hive mind.**

You must also consider that a swarm of Rats is also an [Animal](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types#TOC-Animal) creature. Luckily, being an Animal leaves them susceptible to [Demoralization](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/intimidate#TOC-Demoralize-Opponent). However, many Swarms (including [Spiders](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/vermin/spider/spider-swarm) and [Wasps](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/vermin/bees-and-wasps/wasp/wasp-swarm/)) are composed of [Vermin](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types#TOC-Vermin):

> Mindless: No Intelligence score, and immunity to all mind-affecting effects (charms, compulsions, **morale effects**, patterns, and phantasms).

Additionally, as has elsewhere been stated, Blistering Invective is [[language-dependent]](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic)

> A language-dependent spell uses intelligible language as a medium for communication. If the target cannot understand or hear what the caster of a language-dependent spell says, the spell has no effect, even if the target fails its saving throw.

---

So an *Animal* Swarm *could* be intimidated by an area effect (but not a simple Intimidate check), but you would need to speak a language that they do (and Rats/Rat Swarms, like most animals, speak no language).